# GGTS 3.2 to 3.6.3 upgrade instructions

Tags: maven, ggts

Need to update my GGTS 3.2 using grails 2.2.1 to GGTS 3.6.3 grails 2.4.4. Are there a set of instructions out there to help with this? I didn't set up the IDE to begin with - it was handed to me all set up - so i'm not super familiar with what all needs to be done. I'm on a system with an air gap but it has it's own maven repo setup. I'm getting stuck trying to open my application in the new GGTS as it can't find some plugins. Does the new version of GGTS still use maven? Is there a way i can set up a local maven repo like you could with GGTS 3.2?

Any help would be appreciated. I'm at a total standstill

I have a copy of GGTS 3.6.3 and i imported the project into it. Trying to start the app or refresh dependencies and I'm getting stuck unable to find jcl-over-slf4j 1.7.5 (i think, dont have it in front of me). Would like to set up a local repo